# Ошибка IndexOutOfBoundsException при условной конструции

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

У меня простой код, который нормально работает. Но, когда срабатывает условие if (!_isEmpty), выскакивает ошибка IndexOutOfBoundsException. Если убрать условную конструкцию, то все отлично работает. Что я делаю неправильно?

Упрощенный вариант:

```
val listState = mutableStateListOf<Post>()

LazyColumn()
{
    itemsIndexed(items = listState, itemContent =
    {_, item ->
        Row()
        {
            Text(item.title)
            Text(item.text)
            Text(item.sum)
        }
    })
}

listState.clear()
listState.add(Post(title = "Name", text = "Subject", sum = "Sum"))
listState.add(Post(title = _title, text = _text, sum = _sum))
if (!_isEmpty)
{
    listState.add(Post(title = _title2, text = _text2, sum = _sum2))
    listState.add(Post(title = _title3, text = _text3, sum = _sum3))
}
```

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 12, size 12
at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.MutableIntervalList.checkIndexBounds(IntervalList.kt:183)
at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.MutableIntervalList.get(IntervalList.kt:166)
at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutIntervalContent.getKey(LazyLayoutIntervalContent.kt:86)
at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListItemProviderImpl.getKey(LazyListItemProvider.kt:85)

Comment: И откуда взялось `items = list`? видимо там ожидалось items = listState?

Comment: Ошибка редактирования, упрощал код и неправильно написал.

Comment: Суть в том, что у вас каждое .Add планирует рекомпозицию, которая перезапускает весь этот код, а поскольку `mutableStateListOf<Post>` не захвачен remember, то он пересоздается (и clear ничего не делает). А далее вступает в дело магия compose которая делает рекомпозицию внутренностей LazyColumn, где может быть захвачена ссылка на listState, которую вы обнуляете или что то другое.

В общем деталей магии не знаю, но проблема в том что вы должны использовать remember чтобы listState  не создавался каждый раз, и понимать что этот код с Add рекурсивно вызывает сам себя

Comment: Спасибо. Про remember совсем забыл. Теперь все работает.